# different scheme procedure for "or"

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, procedure

I am currently studying scheme and came across the following question:

prove or disprove the following statement:
the procedure my-or:

```
     (define my-or
       (lambda (test1 test2)
            (if test1
                #t
                test2)))
```

works the same as the built-in procedure "or" with two arguments. 
tipp:

> (or)               = #f

```
(or <a1> ... <an>) = (if <a1>
                          #t
                         (or <a2> ... <an>))
```

if you disprove the statement, find a program where the difference between the two
procedures can be noticed.

so, I believe there is no difference between the two procedures, since they both work the same way for two arguments (portrayed by this tree-diagram that is based on the racket-documentation of the procedure if and or):

```
                       if/or
                    ..     ..
                 #f          #t
               ..              ..
            test2                outcome: #t
          ..     ..
        #f         #t
      ..             ..
   outcome: #f        outcome: #t
```

and also, because if I rewrite my-or in the way it is mentioned in the second tipp
I still get the same output, for example:

```
     > (my-or (= 10 10) (> 2 5)) 
       --> #t
     > (my-or (> 23 42) (< 5 2)) 
       --> #t
```

rewritten:

```
     > (if (= 10 10) #t (or (> 2 5)))
       --> #t
     > (if (> 23 42) #t (or (< 5 2)))
       --> #f
```

the only thing that bothers me is the feeling that we are supposed to disprove the statement due to the mentioning of: "if you disprove the statement, find a programm where the difference between the two procedures can be noticed."

This is why I am not wondering if somebody has an idea to disprove the statement or if somebody can otherwise confirm my idea how to prove the statement to be right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the procedure-based version `my-or` is different from the built-in `or`. To prove it, just try this:

```
(or 1 (/ 1 0))
=> 1

(my-or 1 (/ 1 0))
=> /: division by zero
```

Explanation:

- The built-in `or` is a *special form*, meaning: the evaluation rules that normally apply for procedures are different for `or` (and by the way, the same is true for `and`)
- `or` short-circuits the evaluation of its parameters: the value of the first parameter that returns non-false is returned as the result, and the rest of the parameters will *not* be evaluated!
- `my-or` performs a normal function call, and *all* its parameters will be evaluated *before* passing them to `my-or`'s body
- The example above shows that clearly: `or` doesn't evaluate the division by zero, it returns as soon as it finds the first non-false value, whereas `my-or` evaluates *both* parameters before proceeding, and it fails because it encounters a division by zero

Comment: thank you for your answer! i receive the following output:

> (or #t (/ 1 0))

#t

> (my-or #t (/ 1 0))

/: division by zero


i guess this shows that my-or goes on to evaluate test2, "or" however, only evaluates test1... is this what i am supposed to notice?

Comment: alright - your edit made it clear: thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: i already tried that and just found out that i have to wait - didn't know that before! will do :) have a good evening - or for you afternoon i suppose!

Comment: @user3566193 I'm glad to help you, and a good evening to you too! (it's afternoon around here :))